# Can subclass leave an abstract method unimplemented in java?

Tags: java, abstract-class, abstract-methods

Say class A is super class of B which is superclass of C. A and B are Abstract classes(I've kept them so as no object of actual class A or B can exist, in other words actual class of an object can only be C). I've an Abstract method in A which should not be implemented in B as no such object of actual class B can exist. Therefore, it should be implemented only in C and kept abstract in both A and B.

As far as I know subclasses have to implement abstract methods of superclass in Java. 
Is there a way out? Or do I need to just keep an empty implementation in B?

Comment: An abstract class can extend another abstract class, and it doesn't have to implement the abstract methods.

Comment: Why not try leaving it unimplemented? If you try it, you'll find that you _can_ do this.

Comment: `abstract` more or less just means that this class is not finished yet, because it has abstract methods. So as long as there is still a method not implemented, your class is forced to be `abstract`. That being said, you can expand your class hierarchy as big as you want, and leave the classes abstract. But as soon as you want to have a concrete non-abstract class, everything must be fully implemented.

Comment: @Zabuza Nice Explaination

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `abstract` class can leave `abstract` methods of its superclass unimplemented. So if `B` is also `abstract`, it can leave this method unimplemented and have `C`, the first concrete class in the hierarchy, implement it.